# What features to be included into an e-commerce system written in php?

Tags: php, e-commerce

we are planning to buid an e-commerce system in php. We will not ship the products but offer them as download.

What, in your opinion, are the technical must-haves of such a project? (databases, php modules, server ...).

Thanks very much for your suggestions and tips ;9

best,
heinrich

Answer (score 1):

[PA-DSS](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/pa_dss.shtml) compliant or equivalent